# Su brute-force with dictionary attack

Tags: bash

I have a dictionary file, which contains a list of possible passwords.

I have written the script below to read the file and pass each line into the SU command.

The dictionary contains 637 lines of possible passwords to the machine and my issue is I need to get the password but it takes a lot of time to run

Another thing is that I am new to bash scripting and I would like to it to return password found when the code runs successfully

Below is the code which is am using:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cat .dictionary | while read line ; do
echo $line | su --1
done
```

please

Comment: Would you be _happy_ if a brute force attack could be completed in reasonable time?

Comment: Yes please, another thing which I forgot to add was that I am new to bash scripting and I would like to it to return password found when the code runs successfully

Comment: @SemipeGenesis : If you have two problems, ask two questions. Don't add a new aspect in a comment to an existing question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have no easy way of testing this, but `if echo "$line" | su --1 ; then echo "pswd=|$line|" ; fi` might work. Good luck